# Law of total variance to find $V(Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

Let $X$ be a random variable with values $0$ and $1$.

Let $Y$ be  a random variable with  values in $\mathbb{N_0}$.

Let  $ p \in (0,1)$ and $ P(X=0, Y=n) = p \cdot \frac{e^{-1}}{n!} $ and $ P(X=1, Y=n) = (1-p) \cdot \frac{2^{n}e^{-2}}{n!} $.

Calculate $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$. (expected value and variance)

So We want to use the law of total expectation. $$ E(Y) = E(E(Y|X))= \sum_xE(Y|X=x) \cdot P(X=x)= E(Y|X=0) \cdot p + E(Y|X=1) \cdot (1-p)= \sum_{n=1} n\cdot P(Y=n|X=0)  \cdot p+ \sum_{n=1} n\cdot P(Y=n|X=1)\cdot (1-p) = \sum_{n=1} n\cdot \frac{e^{-1}}{n!} \cdot p +\sum_{n=1} n\cdot \frac{e^{-2}\cdot 2^n}{n!} \cdot(1-p)= e^{-1} \cdot e \cdot p + 2\cdot(1-p)\cdot e^{-2} \cdot \sum_{n=1} \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = p + 2\cdot (1-p) e^{-2} \cdot e^2= p+2 \cdot (1-p)= 2-p $$ 
So far so good. But I never used the law of total variance. Can somebody can only give me "the beginning". What do I mean with "beginning"? I mean that you only write $ E(V(Y|X))$ and$ Var(E(Y|X))$ as sums like I did with $E(E(Y|X))$. Then I will try the rest on my own.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your calculations are correct, however, they can be streamlined: (since we are given the joint distribution, just use it).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))
\\[1ex] &= \sum_{k=0}^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\,\mathsf P(X{=}k\cap Y{=}n)
\\[1ex]&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n\,p\,\mathrm e^{-1}}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n\,(1-p)\,2^n\,\mathrm e^{-2}}{n!}
\\[1ex]&= p\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n ~\mathrm e^{-1}}{n!}+(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n\,2^n\,\mathrm e^{-2}}{n!}
\\[1ex]&=p+2\,(1-p)\\[1ex]&=2-p\end{align}$$

That is very nice, and we *could* find the variance similarly.
$$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2~\mathsf P(X{=}k\cap Y{=}n)\right)-(2-p)^2$$

However, you specifically wanted to apply the Law of Total Variance.   Well that is *most useful* when the conditional distribution and margial distributions are of standard families, with known formula for expectation and variance (or at least are easy to work with).   So when given such a question, **always** first check to see if this is the case.

As indeed this is!   You should be able to recognise that the joint distribution suggests that $X\sim\mathcal{Bern}(1-p)$ and $Y\mid X\sim\mathcal{Poiss}(1+X)$, so therefore: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}k)&=p\,\mathbf 1_{k=0}+(1-p)\,\mathbf 1_{k=1}\\[1ex]\mathsf P(Y{=}n\mid X{=}k)&=\dfrac{(1+k)^n\mathrm e^{-(1+k)}}{n!}\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0,1\},n\in\Bbb N_0}\\[1ex]\mathsf E(Y\mid X)&=1+X\\\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X)&=1+X\\\mathsf E(X)&=1-p\\\mathsf {Var}(X)&=p\,(1-p)\end{align}$$

Thus we just substitute these into the Laws of Totals.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(1+X)\\[1ex]&= 1+(1-p)\\[1ex]&= 2-p\\[3ex]\mathsf{Var}(Y)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the law of total variance is as follows:
$$Var(Y) = E(Var(Y \mid X)) + Var(E(Y \mid X))$$

You can compute $Var(Y \mid X)$ in a number of ways, for example conditioning on $X = x$ like you did with the expectation. For the second term, you calculate $E(Y \mid X)$ like you just did and recall that $Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - {(E(Y))}^2$.